# removing ?= query from select form. (for mod_rewrite)

Tags: php, html, mod-rewrite

hello i'm using this .htaccess code to redirect urls.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^printer/([^/\.]+)/?$ printer.php?id=$1 [L]
```

so any product.php?id=123 will become /product/123.

i changed all the links but i have a problem with html select form no matter what i do i cant get rid of the '?=' signs? how can i get rid of them..?

here is the html code:

```
                <form action="/printer/" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
                    <select name="" id="printers">

                        <?php foreach($printers as $printer): ?>
                            <option class="printer_model" id="#<?php echo $printer['printer_model'] ?>" 
                            value="<?php echo $printer['printer_id']; ?>">
                                <?php echo $printer['printer_model']?>
                            </option>
                        <?php endforeach;?>
                    </select>
```

so i want the action to be /printer/123 but i get /printer/?=123

Comment: The rewrite rule seems to be backwards from the way you understand it to work.  `^product/([^/\.]+)/?$` doesn't match "/product.php?id=123"

Comment: with this code i get /printer/?=123 instead of /printer/123

Comment: forms always produce a ?= (query string). No way to change that. You could use either JS to change the url onsubmit. Or use php to redirect product.php?id=123 to /product/123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML :

```
<form action="/printers.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <select name="printers" id="printers">

        <?php foreach($printers as $printer): ?>
             <option class="printer_model" id="#<?php echo $printer['printer_model'] ?>" 
             value="<?php echo $printer['printer_id']; ?>">
                  <?php echo $printer['printer_model']?>
             </option>
        <?php endforeach;?>
  </select>
```

printers.php :

```
<?PHP
if( isset( $_POST['printers'] ) )
{
    header( 'location: /printer/' . $_POST['printers'] . '/' );
    exit();
}
?>
```

Use from this trick